# TcpClient connection status issue on Network Down

Tags: c#, networking, tcpclient, tcp

I have a `TcpClient` which i am connecting to the machine and everything is working fine.Now one extra step i want to monitor the connection status on very 60 seconds by the help of timer.As per the basic research of the topic i got to know that there is no direct way to test it .So i tried to get it by the response of the recent message sent to the machine when the application goes out of the network.

Here is the code..

```
 // Find out whether the socket is connected to the remote host.

 //Send a message to Machine
 try
 {
  byte[] notify = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello");
  stream.Write(notify, 0, notify.Length);     
 }catch { }

 //Check if it reached to machine or failed 
 bool getConnectionStatus = client.Connected;

 if (getConnectionStatus == true)
     {
         //Do nothing
     }
 else
     {
        //Stop the thread
        _shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0);
        _thread.Abort();

         //Start Again
         _thread = new Thread(DoWork);
         _thread.Start();
      }
```

But the most astonishing thing that is happening in this case is that if the machine is out of the network then also while writing the first time it is able to write and and that's why connection status is coming as connected although it is out of the network.Second time when it is trying to send data it is failing and like expected status is disconnected.

The main problem that i am facing is that once it is disconnected from the network why it is able to send the data .Due to this i loosing all the buffer data which is stored in the machine by that time when network goes off.
Please help me..

Comment: Send a "PING", wait for a "PONG"

Comment: @AlexK. Am sorry i did not get you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, the `Write` operation just sends the data to the network layer; you may get a "success" result before an attempt is made to transmit the data. The network layer may even delay sending the data for a while if the data is small, in an attempt to send one batch of a few messages at once.

What Alex K. said with a few words is that the most reliable way to check a network connection is to wait for a response. If no such response is received within a certain amount of time, the connection is lost.

Lets say you keep using "Hello" and the server should respond with "Yeah!". On the client side, you could extend your current code with:

```
try
{
    byte[] notify = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello");
    stream.Write(notify, 0, notify.Length);
    byte[] notifyResult = new byte[5];
    int bytesRead = stream.Read(notifyResult, 0, 5);
    if (bytesRead == 0)
    {
        // No network error, but server has disconnected
    }

    // Arriving here, notifyResult should contain ASCII "Yeah!" 
}
catch (SocketException)
{
    // Network error
}
```

On the server, you should recognize the "Hello" being sent, and simply respond with "Yeah!". I don't know what your server currently does, but it *could* be something similar to:

```
switch (receivedMessage)
{
    case "Hello":
        stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Yeah!"), 0, 5);
        break;
}
```

Note that you should consider wrapping your messages in information packets, ie:

```
<Message Type> <Message> <Terminator Character>
ie. "KHello\n"
```

Or

```
<Size of Message> <Message Type> <Message> 
ie. "0005KHello"
```

Where message type 'K' is a Keep-alive message, the newline "\n" the terminator character and "0005" the message length excluding the message type.

This way the server will always be able to tell whether it has received the full message, and the message type could indicate whether "Hello" was sent as data or as a keep-alive packet.

Comment: Can you please give me the example or the psudocode connection to my code in the post.Actually i am new to the field so not getting the terms clearly

Comment: @shubhamHegdey Added an example. I hope you can make some progress with it.